# Only focus in the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a search form that can navigate between the results using the arrows up and down key. But only works with the first results, if you want to navigate again you need to focus on the search input text again, I can't navigate pressing up or down again if i don't do this.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaw7g332/6/

Js code:

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('.buscar-icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('p#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('p#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });


});


$("input#search").on("keydown", function(e) {
        var $listItems = $('ul#results li');
        var $listItemsa = $('ul#results li a');

             var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;

    if ( key != 40 && key != 38 ) return;

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if ( key == 40 ) // Down key
    {
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.next();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    else if ( key == 38 ) // Up key
    {
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    $.fn.focusWithoutScrolling = function(){
var x = $(document).scrollLeft(), y = $(document).scrollTop();
  this.focus();
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
  return this; //chainability

};
var $currenta = $current.children();
$currenta.focusWithoutScrolling();
    $current.addClass('selected');
    event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your event listener is only checking the key event on the input field you can add the list of results to the listener like this:

```
$("input#search, #results").on("keydown", function(e) {
.....
});
```

This should allow to navigate the results

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/gaw7g332/8/)